# Redirect user after session_write and setcookie

Tags: php, mysql, redirect, authentication, header

I want to redirect the user after the login to a page, but I always get a "header cannot be modified" error. I know that there should not be an echo or something else before the `header()` command but how is it done in a normal way. User logs in, cookies are set (also session is set), user gets a notification that all things went the right way and he would be redirected to another page?

Here's my php file:

```
<?php
$qry="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email='$email' AND password='".md5($_POST['password'])."'";
$result=mysql_query($qry);

if($result) {
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        $_SESSION['SESS_MEMBER_ID'] = $member['id'];
        $_SESSION['EMAIL'] = $member['email'];
        session_write_close();

        if($remember_me == 1) {
        setcookie("user",$email,time()+(3600*24*365));
        setcookie("pw",md5($_POST['password']),time()+(3600*24*365));
        }

        //header("location: logged.php");  <- doesn't work

                    echo 'you are now logged in';
    }

    else {

        echo 'something went wrong';
        }
}
else {
    die("Query failed");
}
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.
Best regards, john.

Comment: always use `exit;` after `header`. By the way, `md5` is not the best practice to save passwords but still better than plain text.

Comment: please check that you are not echoing any character before `<?php` like space, this is a common mistake.

Answer (score -1):

it should be something like this inside the results function

```
               header("location: logged.php");  

               exit;
```

Comment: Now that would really cause the error the OP is talking about. You're outputting to the screen before trying to redirect them.

Comment: who is op ?? i hear a lot about him i dont know